# Uniqueness of a moment problem over $\int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{\sigma^p}{(1+\sigma)^{2S}} m(\sigma) \: \mathrm d \sigma$ with a finite range in $p$

Tags: moment-problem

A [question over on the physics site](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/345351/some-properties-of-coherent-spin-states) asked about the [moment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_problem)
$$
\int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{\sigma^p}{(1+\sigma)^{2S}} m(\sigma) \: \mathrm d \sigma
=
\frac{p!(2S-p)!}{(2S+1)!},
$$
where $S=0,1,2,\ldots$ and $p=0,1,2,\ldots,2S$, which turns out to have as a solution
$$
m(\sigma) = \frac{1}{(1+\sigma)^2},
$$
where the solution can be verified by a direct calculation. Given its context in [the original paper](https://dx.doi.org/10.1088/0305-4470/4/3/009), it is reasonable to ask whether this solution is unique or not. Given how close this is to the standard moment problem over $p$, I'm inclined to think that it probably is, but the finite range in $p$ makes that more complicated. So: is this moment problem determinate? If so, how does one prove it? If not, what other solutions are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unique.  Even if you only look at the $p=0$ data, and just ask for the $S$-th moments of $X = 1/(1+\sigma)^2$ you have enough data for the Hausdorff moment problem to give uniqueness.  (The distribution of $X$ is supported on $[0,1]$, the moments of $X$ specify its distribution uniquely; from the distribution of $X$ the formula for $m(\cdot)$ drops out.)